# python find and replace all values under a certain key in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, json, replace, nested

Given any supplied key and value, I want to replace every value under that key no matter where it is in the dictionary

Example:

```
input -> key='a', value='HELLO', 
{
  'a': [1],
  'b': {
    'c': 1,
    'a': {
      'd': 'string',
      'e': [1, 2]
    },
    'f': [1, 3]
  }
}

output ->
{
  'a': 'HELLO',
  'b': {
    'c': 1,
    'a': 'HELLO',
    'f': [1, 3]
  },
}
```

Comment: Your input has a key `f` inside the `b` dict. The output that ended up as a root-level key in the dict. Is that a mistake?

Comment: Good catch @Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion. You'll need to supply logic for diving into each container type you care about supporting. As an example, this is how you could handle values in nested dicts or lists.

```
def replace_nested_key(data, key, value):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        return {
            k: value if k == key else replace_nested_key(v, key, value)
            for k, v in data.items()
        }
    elif isinstance(data, list):
        return [replace_nested_key(v, key, value) for v in data]
    else:
        return data
```

Comment: I forgot to include list of dictionaries as a possibility, thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through every key and value pair in the array until you get the specified name, and set the value to it.

```
def find_and_replace_values_in_nested_dictionary(dictionary, key, value):
    if isinstance(dictionary, dict):
        for k, v in dictionary.items():
            if k == key:
                dictionary[k] = value
            else:
                if isinstance(v, dict):
                    solution(v, key, value)
                elif isinstance(v, list):
                    for i in v:
                        if isinstance(i, dict):
                            solution(i, key, value)
    return dictionary

dictionary = {
    'a': [1],
    'b': {
        'c': 1,
        'a': {
            'd': 'string',
            'e': [1, 2]
        },
        'f': [1, 3]
    }
}
print(find_and_replace_values_in_nested_dictionary(dictionary, 'a', 'HELLO'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `recursion` to make things easy.

Instead of modifying the original dictionary I am creating a `copy` of the `dictionary` and modifying it.

The method `change` recursively call itself.

```
import copy

a = {
  'a': [1],
  'b': {
    'c': 1,
    'a': {
      'd': 'string',
      'e': [1, 2]
    },
    'f': [1, 3]
  }
}

def change(a:dict, key, value):
    n = copy.deepcopy(a)
    for k, v in a.items():
        if k == key:
            n[k] = value
        elif isinstance(v, dict) :
            n[k] = change(v, key, value)
    return n


print(change(a=a,key='a',value='HELLO'))
```

## Output:

```
{'a': 'HELLO', 'b': {'c': 1, 'a': 'HELLO', 'f': [1, 3]}}
```

ps : Thanks Flakes for `isinstance` suggestion to identify the `dictionary` type.

Comment: Use `isinstance` instead of `type(...) is` for checking class types. Using `type(...) is` restricts the ability to use subclasses, when all you really care about is if it follows the `dict` contract., e.g. `assert (type(defaultdict(list)) is dict) == False`